# Code convention for if-else, for statements in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, conventions, if-statement

(code convention doc: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-142311.html#449)

I've always written if-else statements as:

```
if(condition) {
    statements;
} else {
    statements;
}
```

however, in the Java code conventions document, it says to write it like this:

```
if (

condition) {


statements;
} else {


statements;
}
```

And also, I've always written for statements like this:

```
for(initialization;condition;update) {
    statements;
}
```

But the coding convention says:

```
for (

initialization;

condition;

update) {


statements;
}
```

The indentation and spacing seems unnecessarily cumbersome to me. Which is the correct/better way and why?

Comment: i.e. should I follow convention?

Comment: It seems the conventions page has problems. Read the pdf instead:
http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/CodeConventions.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that might just be a formatting problem on that HTML page?

Have a look at the PDF, I think it looks better there:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

There they have the conditions on the same line as the if.

Comment: Haha brilliant. I should have thought of this earlier. I thought it was strange :)

Comment: +1, one other evidence: The document says "The enclosed statements should be indented one more level than the compound statement.", but the 'statement' displayed does not follow this convention, which makes me believe the format itself has problem.

Comment: The link broke, but using the wayback machine I managed to salvage the PDF:
https://web.archive.org/web/20121102200843/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you are employed somewhere, and they enforce a specific convention, then shut up and use it.  Otherwise, just do whatever you feel works best for you and don't worry about what everyone else thinks.  It is more important to write code than bicker about how to paint bike sheds.

EDIT:  I just saw that that page was hideously misformatted, probably due to the Oracle-Sun buyout.  COME FROM's comment has the correct Java standard documentation, so if your question was which is the correct documentation then you should use the link he posted.  However, I will still stand by my original sentiment that this is something which deeply does not matter.

Comment: I'm studying software engineering and they're teaching code conventions. I want to know if people really use this method at a workplace or will they define what convention you use?

Comment: If that is what the professor wants, then use that convention.  The consequence of not doing so could risk your grade.  If you aren't being judged, then what does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

What i feel, is that the code conventions are for formatting the code, so that if some other guy reads that, there is no such problem in understanding the code,

Untill, you are writing the code in such a way, that any one can understand the code, just by a look into it, then its fine not to use tha Java Code Conventions.